# print lines that first column not in the list

Tags: bash

I have a list of numbers in a file

```
cat to_delete.txt
2
3
6
9
11
```

and many txt files in one folder. Each file has tab delimited lines (can be more lines than this).

```
3 0.55667 0.66778 0.54321 0.12345
6 0.99999 0.44444 0.55555 0.66666
7 0.33333 0.34567 0.56789 0.34543
```

I want to remove the lines that the first number ($1 for awk) is in to_delete.txt and print only the lines that the first number is not in to_delete.txt. The change should be replacing the old file.

Expected output

```
7 0.33333 0.34567 0.56789 0.34543
```

This is what I got so far, which doesn't remove anything;

```
for file in *.txt; do awk '$1 != /2|3|6|9|11/' "$file" > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" "$file"; done
```

I've looked through so many similar questions here but still cannot make it work. I also tried grep -v -f to_delete.txt and sed -n -i '/$to_delete/!p'

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea was this:

```
printf "%s\n" *.txt | xargs -n1 sed -i "$(sed 's!.*!/& /d!' to_delete.txt)"
```

1. `printf "%s\n" *.txt` - outputs the *.txt files each on separate lines
2. `| xargs -n1` execute the following command for each line passing the line content as the input
3. `sed -i` - edit file in place
4. `$( ... )` - command substitution
5. `sed 's!.*!/^& /d!' to_delete.txt` - for each line in to_delete.txt, append the line with `/^` and suffix with `/d`. That way from the list of numbers I get a list of regexes to delete, like:

```
/^2 /d
/^3 /d
/^6 /d
```

and so on. Which tells `sed` to delete lines matching the regex - line starting with the number followed by a space.

But I think `awk` would be simpler. You could do:

```
awk '$1 != 2 && $1 != 3 && $1 != 6 ... and so on ...`
```

but that would be longish, unreadable. It's easier to read the map from the file and then check if the number is in the array:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ map[$1] } FNR!=NR && !($1 in map)' to_delete.txt "$file"
```

The `FNR==NR` is true only for the first file. So when we read it, we set the `map[$1]` (we "set" it, just so such element exists). Then `FNR!=NR` is true for the second file, for which we check if the first element is the key in the map. If it is not, the expression is true and the line gets printed out.

all together:

```
for file in *.txt; do awk 'FNR==NR{ map[$1] } FNR!=NR && !($1 in map)' to_delete.txt "$file" > "$tmp"; mv "$tmp" "$file"; done
```

Comment: I didn't know about FNR==NR, and didn't know you can just use map like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a)' delete file
```

Output:

```
7 0.33333 0.34567 0.56789 0.34543
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {       # hash records in delete file to a hash
    a[$1]       
    next
}
!($1 in a)      # if $1 not found in record in files after the first, output
' delete files*   # mind the file order
```